# using "as far as" or "to as far as"

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context, word-in-context

I have a sentence:

> I am fascinated by traveling, but I did not imagine that I could ***go to***
>   as far as America

Or

> I am fascinated by traveling, but I did not imagine that I could ***go*** as
>   far as America

Comment: You had "to to as far as America" in your first sentence, but I think that was just a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Both "to" and "as far as" are prepositions.

> I did not imagine that I could go *to* America

Ok.

> I did not imagine that I could go *as far as* America

Ok.

You generally don't stack prepositions together. Imagine other examples such as "on", "under", "near". Would you say "under near the bed"?  Not usually.

So, in this case use either "to" or "as far as", but not both of them.